# female dvi-d to male vga connection

Tags: connector, vga, display

I have a monitor which has male vga and a pc which has female dvi-d output. How can I connect my monitor to my pc? There are many cheap connectors like 5-6$ but some people says "they don't work, there is no way to connect them". Is there any idea?

Comment: Try and error, I would say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use an active adapter that translates between the analog VGA signals and the digital DVI-D signals. Such adapters do exist, but they cost *much* more than $5-6.

Answer (score 0):

Is the output from the PC definitely DVI-D? Or does it have the analogue signal in there as well (DVI-I)?

Assuming the graphics output on the PC does include analogue signals (as that seems much more common), you don't need an active adaptor, just a DVI -> 15 pin HDD VGA adaptor. With that you can then just use a 15 pin HDD VGA cable to connect the monitor to the PC.